# How to make to rotation relative to each other? Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a problem with this script

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObrotPily : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float rotate;
    public float rotateStrong;

    void Update()
    {
        rotate += rotateStrong;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotate);

        while (rotate > 359)
            rotate = 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the object (4 saws) moves on green line but they should follow blue line (the each other), they should
turning around blue line.

[Here's a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSJA2.png)

Comment: Whats your hierarchy look like?

Comment: Just a side note: Try to write the names in your code in English. Understanding names is extremely helpful in understanding the code itself. This code is short so its ok but in longer code many will not even bother to read it with native nameing because it multiples the effort needed to understand it.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/Fm4sYyg) I rewrote the code to english language.

Answer (score 0):

Just use .localRotation instead of .rotation, it should help

Comment: Like that? `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotacja);`